# How can I write a generic function that uses the type of an enum member instead of the enum itself?

Tags: typescript, generics, enums

The [TypeScript documentation on enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#union-enums-and-enum-member-types) says:

> enum members also become types as well!

I would like to have a function that takes a generic value that is an enum member and uses the specific enum member's type.

I see that I can use the enum member as a type:

```
enum Kind {
    Apple,
    Banana,
}

type Example1 = Kind.Apple;
```

I can use the enum member in a generic type context:

```
interface Wrapper<K> {
    kind: K;
}

type Example2 = Wrapper<Kind.Apple>;
```

When I pass the enum member to a function, it loses the fact that it's a specific enum member and instead makes it the parent's enum type:

```
const returned = <K>(kind: K): Wrapper<K> => ({
    kind,
})

const theValue = returned(Kind.Apple);

// Type 'Kind' is not assignable to type 'Kind.Apple'.
const butNot: Example2 = theValue;
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20Kind%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Apple%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Banana%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Can%20use%20the%20enum%20member%20as%20a%20type%0D%0Atype%20Example1%20%3D%20Kind.Apple%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Wrapper%3CK%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20kind%3A%20K%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Can%20use%20the%20enum%20member%20in%20a%20generic%0D%0Atype%20Example2%20%3D%20Wrapper%3CKind.Apple%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20returned%20%3D%20%3CK%3E(kind%3A%20K)%3A%20Wrapper%3CK%3E%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20kind%2C%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20theValue%20%3D%20returned(Kind.Apple)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Type%20'Kind'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'Kind.Apple'.%0D%0Aconst%20butNot%3A%20Example2%20%3D%20theValue%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: Is this a complaint about type inference? If so, your expectations may be a bit high... :) You can always manually pass in the generic type: `returned<Kind.Apple>(Kind.Apple)`.

Comment: Another workaround is to write `const returned = <K extends Kind>(kind: K): Wrapper<K> => ({
    kind,
})`, but that makes `returned` applicable to `Kind` subtypes only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why `kind` parameter type is widened from `Kind.Apple` to `Kind` is spelled out in https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676 :

> During type argument inference for a call expression the type inferred
>   for a type parameter T is widened to its widened literal type if:
>
> - all inferences for T were made to top-level occurrences of T within the particular parameter type, and
> - T has no constraint or its constraint does not include primitive or literal types, and
> - T was fixed during inference or T does not occur at top-level in the return type.

If, as mentioned in the second bullet, you add constraint for generic parameter `T` it will start inferring specific literal type. The price for that is that it makes `returned` applicable to subtypes of `Kind` only.

```
enum Kind {
    Apple,
    Banana,
}

interface Wrapper<K> {
    kind: K;
}

const returned = <K extends Kind>(kind: K): Wrapper<K> => ({
    kind,
})

const theValue = returned(Kind.Apple);

const thisWorksNow: Wrapper<Kind.Apple> = theValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly specify what the generic type should be on the call to `returned`:

```
enum Kind {
    Apple,
    Banana,
}

interface Wrapper<K> {
    kind: K;
}

const returned = <K>(kind: K): Wrapper<K> => ({
    kind,
})

const theValue = returned<Kind.Apple>(Kind.Apple);

const thisWorksNow: Wrapper<Kind.Apple> = theValue;
```